# Trouble identifying an Error (array to listview)

Tags: android, arrays, listview, bluetooth, runtime-error

I have a bit of a problem that I have now spent 2 weeks trying to solve. I will try to be as detailed as possible, but if something is unclear, please ask.
I'm working on a bluetooth chat application. Everything works well, except for 4 lines of code that cause the crash.
I have made a secondary activity where you are sent when you click connect.

This is the layout (connection_activity.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<TextView android:id="@+id/title_paired_devices"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_paired_devices"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#666"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
/>
<ListView android:id="@+id/paired_devices"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<TextView android:id="@+id/title_new_devices"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/title_other_devices"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:background="#666"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
/>
<ListView android:id="@+id/new_devices"
    android:textIsSelectable="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    android:layout_weight="2"
/>
<Button android:id="@+id/button4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_scan"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is just a simple activity with 2 lists to display the paired and available devices (where they are clickable in order to connect with one of them).

Then there is the source code (ConnectionActivity.java)

```
/* In this activity I will manage the secondary layout (for bluetooth connection)*/

package com.andrecl.interapption;

import java.util.Set;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ConnectionActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

/* Initializing part */
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
BluetoothSocket mSocket;
BluetoothDevice mDevice;

public static String EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS = "device_address"; // this is the
                                                           // number
                                                                // code of
                                                                // the
                                                                // devices
Button scanButton; //the scan button
StartDiscover startDiscover; //start discover thread

/* For intent request */
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

/* Arrays for storing the lists of paired devices and found devices */
private ArrayAdapter<String> mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mNewDevicesArrayAdapter;

/* Called when the activity is first created. */
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.connection_activity);

    // Get the local Bluetooth adapter (as in the other activity)
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    /* Make sure bt is on! */
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) { 
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(
                BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }

    /* Initialize array adapters. One for already paired devices and one for newly discovered devices */
    mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.connection_activity);
    mNewDevicesArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.connection_activity);


 /* Find and set up the ListView for paired devices */
    ListView pairedListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.paired_devices);
    pairedListView.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter);
    pairedListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener); //later implemented if you click on a device

    /* Find and set up the ListView for newly discovered devices */
    ListView newDevicesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.new_devices);
    newDevicesListView.setAdapter(mNewDevicesArrayAdapter);
    newDevicesListView.setOnItemClickListener(mDeviceClickListener); //later implemented if you click on a device

 // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); 

    // Register for broadcasts when discovery has finished
    filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
   this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    // Get a set of currently paired devices
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    /*Finally we start listening if the scanbutton is pressed*/
    startDiscover = new StartDiscover();
    scanButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
    scanButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    /* List of paired devices */ //removed the array printing due to crash
    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        findViewById(R.id.title_paired_devices).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Paired devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
    } else {
         Toast.makeText(this, "No paired devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_paired).toString();
         mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
    }
}

/* The scan button */
public void onClick(View v) {
    startDiscover.start();
    v.setVisibility(View.GONE); // so you can't use the button again (avoid Button spamming). GONE: This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes
}



/*The Discover thread*/
private class StartDiscover extends Thread{
    private Handler dHandler = new Handler();

    public void run(){
        dHandler.post(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
                toast();

            }
        });
    }
}
public void toast(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning - Please wait", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

// The BroadcastReceiver that listens for discovered devices and
// changes the title when discovery is finished
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // If it's already paired, skip it, because it's been listed already DEACTIVATED DUE TO CRASH
               if (device.getBondState() != BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED) {   
                 mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
              } 
          // When discovery is finished, change the Activity title
        } else if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED.equals(action)) {
            setTitle(R.string.select_device); //Due to space issues, the instructions are displayed in the title.

            /*If no devices found ... removed due to crashing*/
            if (mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.getCount() == 0) {
                String noDevices = getResources().getText(R.string.none_found).toString();
                mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);
            } 
          }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // Make sure we're not doing discovery anymore
    if (mBluetoothAdapter != null) {
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }

    // Unregister broadcast listeners
    this.unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
}

// The on-click listener for all devices in the ListViews
private OnItemClickListener mDeviceClickListener = new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> av, View v, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // Cancel discovery because it's costly and we're about to connect
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        // Get the device MAC address, which is the last 17 chars in the View
        String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
        String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);

        // Create the result Intent and include the MAC address
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DEVICE_ADDRESS, address);

        // Set result and finish this Activity
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
};


}
```

Now what causes the whole App to crash (if I remove these lines it doesn't crash) are:
**mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());**
and
**mPairedDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);**

and later
**mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());**
and
**mNewDevicesArrayAdapter.add(noDevices);**

These four lines seem to be the problem. Is anyone able to identify what I did wrong?

Thanks for your time,

EDIT:
I'm so sorry, here is the LogCat:

```
    05-22 19:25:27.592: D/libEGL(27711): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-22 19:25:27.600: D/libEGL(27711): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-22 19:25:27.600: D/libEGL(27711): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX540_120.so
05-22 19:25:27.787: D/OpenGLRenderer(27711): Enabling debug mode 0
05-22 19:25:30.928: D/OpenGLRenderer(27711): Flushing caches (mode 0)
05-22 19:25:44.225: E/ArrayAdapter(27711): You must supply a resource ID for a TextView
05-22 19:25:44.225: D/AndroidRuntime(27711): Shutting down VM
05-22 19:25:44.225: W/dalvikvm(27711): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40bfc1f8)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:386)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:362)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2210)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:822)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4709)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2240)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12775)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1117)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2505)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4514)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:379)
05-22 19:25:44.233: E/AndroidRuntime(27711):    ... 30 more
05-22 19:26:44.717: I/Process(27711): Sending signal. PID: 27711 SIG: 9
```

Comment: can you post your logcat @Marshall

Comment: Looks like `device` is null.  You don't seem to instantiate it anywhere.  As Iftikar has said, we need the logcat to be sure.

Comment: Looking again, you don't even seem to be *declaring* device.  What is it supposed to be?

Comment: I'm so, sorry. I've added the LogCat.

Comment: device is what you are paired with (or the found ones).
I've used the Android Sample from ADK as a base...

Comment: You have many problems in your code.  I recommend some basic Java tutorials, learning how to read logcat and learning how to use the debugger before trying something this complex.  For now, Google for these - `ArrayAdapter requires the resource ID to be a TextView` and `android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView`

Comment: Thank you. I'll check it out.
I wish I could take the time to learn this from the bottom, but it is unfortunately a short university course (had 8 short lectures about android and have to make this app for a grade). I have no experience with Java (only some l´playing around for some days), only with C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue and thought it would be a good idea to write it here, to help anyone who may have a similar issue. 
Apparently I just had to add

```
.toString()
```

so that it could add the string to the Listview. I also used iterator for the list of paired devices, though I doubt it had any significant effect.